# Dual power source design

Tags: power, led, switching

This circuit is simpler version of my current setup. I have connected these high power LEDs in parallel and controlling its intensity level using PWM signal generated by FPGA. The AC to DC converter which I am using currently gives max current of 2.2 Amps. In total 32 LEDS are connected to this power source in similar way. My requirement is to monetarily boost the intensity of LEDs to it peak value.So I am thinking to to use Lead Acid battery which will boost the current and intensity of LEDs will be at its peak. This switching between DC supply from converter and from battery should be controllable and with minimum switching delay.How should I approach in designing this circuit.

DataSheet of LED [BXRA-56C5300]
http://www.bridgelux.com/sites/default/files/resource_media/DS25-Bridgelux-RS-Array-Data-Sheet-2014.01.27.pdf

Thanks!

Datasheet of power transistor used
https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IPP_B_I80P04P4L-08-DS-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4625c167129015c348992484d42

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhHfaI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @RonBeyer how should I approach in designing this switching circuit. I was thinking to use High side OR-ing FET controller.Please consult with other options

Comment: Due to wide variance in Vf vs tolerance and temp, you must use a CC linear or switching regulator on low or high side with PWM if you want dim control.  Can't you make SMPS 26V? or 2.2A current source?  Do you really have 32x 50W chips?  How many hours of power did you expect?

Comment: Hope you are aware of significant cooling design required like an  overclocked CPU.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 yes . In total I am using 64 50W LEDs. 32 are powered using each AC to DC 24V converter. Since forward voltage of these LEDs is high I had to connect them in parallel.

The requirement is to supply high current for time duration of max 2 sec so LEDs will glow at max intensity. The max rated current for these LEDs is 4 Amps. I need each LED to glow at its  max intensity for this duration in order to trigger photosynthesis activity .

Comment: The chip will heat up in <1s without heatsink and with heatsink depends on duty cycle of peak power.    YOu could run from AC line rectifed with current limiter and wired in a suitable par./ser. array to be just below rectified DC voltage.. With more data, I can help.. e.g. 120V or 230Vac?  rep rate of 2sec  ( and of course double insulated)

Comment: or use 2 series 12V SLA batteries , cheaper and use in parallel with 3A charger at float voltage of 27V.. datasheet for DC conv?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 First of all thank you for proactively replying.By chip you are referring to LED right? Yes all the LEDs are attached to large heatsink bar . On each bar 8 LEDs are attached. Just to clarify , the circuit will be running normally from AC to DC converter shown in circuit. This circuit should switch to another source (Lead Acid Battery, I have 3 car batteries which I can use for testing) upon receiving the signal will run for max 2 secs and then again switch back to original source. 

I am aware of using current limiting resistor but thinking on switching ckt.

Comment: I would use battery array off 24V with 27V nominal float charger x A shared  but steady power draw is 64x50W =3.2kW so heat exhaust needed too unless in winter. Sounds like a grow-op.  Or better run off AC without chargers using 300W halogen tubes in series as current limiters.  ( but operating at 10% )   so 5 strings of 24V in series  off 120V with 1 ohm cold R halogen 300W+ tubes in series. Thus only 10~20V across tubes .. ballpark...

Comment: if 120vac then 10A diode bridge and AC wiring with MOV protection, insulation rating is 300V on LEDs then use cct in my answer for regulated 2A boost pulse

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 yes its a growth chamber.But need to use specifically these LED to meet the wavelength requirement of experiment.Using 24 V with charger is ideal for this experiment for boosting the output.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I am bit confused over here .In your answer you have shown leds in series . But in my design they are 32 LEDs connected in parallel with 24V supply DC supply and intensity controlled via PWM signal to gate of transistor.Currently I am getting roughly 2.2 A current flow through each LED. I need to boost this to 4A.Sorry if I am missing something. Its my first approach for the design after school.

Comment: One string is 24V which is a series string of LEDs I put ... in between. What duty cycle. ? I showed how to regulate with a resistor and   FET , there are many ways to do this. including with adding a choke and clamp diode.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I can't make changes to current circuit which is already on experiment. So will have to build another one which can be connected with battery to regulate 24V 4 amps going through each LED.So effectively circuit should regulate 24V and each LED should be able to draw 4A so effective should handle 3.2KW of power.

Comment: Nope, you cannot draw 4A if Vf>24V,, From datasheet you need 28~32V

Comment: You will never get the answer you need without full details of what you have , need and can afford.  Power, V, Temp rise, heat sinks, layout etc

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 kindly pardon me for not supplying full details.So should using SLA and regulating voltage between this voltage range and using high side  OR-ing FET controller like LM5050-Q1 for switching between 24 DC supply and regulated voltage from SLA would work.

Comment: you want >4kW!!, I might consider a 24V truck battery with  split phase 5Hp ACmotor/ DC alternator ( used parts) on suitable pulleys to get 28.8V at the battery nearest the load. But test LED's first with pulses to find Vf/If to see if that is enough voltage (marginal) then use suitable ultralow RdsOn FETs with comparator for current limit to avoid thermal runaway. (See schematic low V drop is a must)  Running hot lowers Vf 5% which raises If [A] but also reduces MTBF 50%/10'C rise. Then use twisted pair welding cable for everything. When that works you can use PWM and toss the 24V regulators

Comment: Low side Nch are better than hi-side Pch for $ vs current rating and you need a rating >5x load

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN1dhZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Open collector comparator shown